# Converting NSJSONSerialization to ios 4

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, ios4

I'm converting a project that supports ios 5 to ios 4 and having some difficulties.
It uses the class `AFNetworking` and my problem is in the following line:

iOS 5: (works great)

```
self.responseJSON =[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:self.responseData options:0 error:&error];
```

Because `NSJSONSerialization` isn't supported in iOS 4 I'm using this:

```
self.responseJSON = AFJSONDecode(self.responseData, &error);
```

What gives me the error:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_AFJSONDecode", referenced from:
      -[AFJSONRequestOperation responseJSON] in AFJSONRequestOperation.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Comment: Do you have a really, really good reason to support iOS 4? Maintaining compatibility for an existing app I can understand, but _adding it in now_?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Requirements section of the AFNetworking page](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking#requirements) states:

> For compatibility with iOS 4.3, use the latest 0.10.x release.

Glancing at the [code for version 0.10.1](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/tree/0.10.1), I see the file [AFJSONUtilities.m](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/blob/0.10.1/AFNetworking/AFJSONUtilities.m), which appears to handle JSON decoding. This is not present in the latest version of AFNetowrking since it requires iOS 5 or above, which has NSJSONSerialization.

You might want to try version 0.10.1, if you have not already, rather than modifying the current version to work on iOS 4 because you may run into additional roadblocks after dealing with the JSON problem.

Comment: Don't know how I missed that. That definitely made some progress. I've posted a followup question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14118166/the-jkdictionary-class-is-private-to-jsonkit-and-should-not-be-used-in-this-fash.

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is to use a third party library for JSON processing on iOS 4 and earlier. I would recommend JSONKit. https://github.com/johnezang/JSONKit